# WPF : Storyboard - Add animation to move windows

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

Am creating WPF windows form application.

There are bout 7-8 usercontrols. Each user control has back and next button. When I click Next button, second form will appear and on Back previous form will appear. (You can image this with any installer)

Am able to show/hide forms. I want to add animation. As soon as I click Next button, control 1 must slide to left and control2 must come in from right (Imagine VS2012 setup)

I am using storyboard and able to slide controls but issue is control2 comes only after control1 disappear.

Please help me or provide code to achieve something like Visual Studio 2012 setup screens animation.

Am using this [link](http://www.fyslexicduck.com/2011/05/page-transition-control-for-wpf.html) (Page Transition Control) for reference.

Comment: When do you start the two animaitons? Can you show your code for the animation? I cannot see any problem if you start the slide-in and slide-out animation at the same time.

Comment: When user clicks Next/Back button, animation must start. Current window should move left and new window must follow current window and come in.

Am using Slide-in and out but it waits for first window to slide out and then start slide-in of other window

Comment: from the link you provided I see that the next page is shown just after the previous aniamation is completed: `hidePage.Completed += hidePage_Completed;`. If you did the same thing, it is no wonder that you have that problem. If you do want the two animation starting at the same time, call them at the same time.

Comment: yes. I want both animations to start parallel so that i can get smooth animation. I dont want blank screen between screen transformation.